# can we deploye Page Layouts using ChangeSets

Tags: deployment, change-set

Can we move pagelayouts from org to another org using ChangeSets.

Comment: i did drag and drop in sandbox.it became an issue with the client.need suggestion,how to move this..

Comment: I've removed the 'urgent' from your question, as that is considered very rude here. Your question is also very basic. Did you try this yourself before asking your question? The answer to your question as asked is, simply, yes. If you're running into other problems, you'll need to provide more details. I've downvoted this question for lack of detail and lack of research effort.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/migrate_changesets.htm)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can !

Just go to Setup > Outbound Change Sets.

Then, create a new change set, and after that, just click on the "add" button in the "Change Set Components" section.

In the components list you will see "Page Layout".

:)